# on the frontend I got nothing but a ">" sign

Tags: front-end

I just designed my website offline and when I tried to make it online I got nothing but a ">" sign on the page.
I got backend of the site correctly, but I do not know what happened to the frontend.
when I changed the template to default template the problem solved.
And when I change error reporting to development mode I got a lot of this error:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in
>   /home/alitk/public_html/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/helper.php on line
>   553

and

> Strict Standards: Non-static method
>   NSP_GK4_Thumbs::checkSpecialImages() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/alitk/public_html/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/gk_classes/gk.thumbs.php
>   on line 127

Comment: any errors in the error log or console?

Comment: Where should I check for errors?

Comment: Error reporting is on system default and there is no error in the front-end of the site

Comment: You could try changing the default template to see if the problem with the template or one of your extensions. Also, set error reporting to "Development".

Comment: As mentioned before, check the error slogs on your server and also your browser console. We can't help without knowing anything

Comment: What template are you using, obviously an error in the front-end of that template if the default Joomla one works.

Comment: `assigned by reference in...`.... in what? It should mentioned a file and line number. This is the key information that is required to help you. If this is **not** a core Joomla file, please provide the code on this line

Comment: Ok this is a 3rd party extension related issue. You need to contact the developer of `mod_news_pro_gk4`. It's their extension, therefore they are the ones who should be providing the support ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is related to mod_news_pro_gk4, because this kind of errors usually don't break the site, they are informational only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a different setup between your development and your production site. As you are migrating from one location to a very different one, you can find fatal errors. You have to check all system requirements in the new server.

For example, ionCube extension, used in some closed commercial extensions, is a common nasty surprise.

To solve the issue, I would begin disabling non-core system plug-ins, one by one, until the page is loaded successfully. If not, try to uninstall every extension to narrow the search, even if you have to go back to one of the default templates. Once you find the problem, you create a modified backup from the development site.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try in order to find the problem, and without actually seeing your site it's hard to know what's causing this.

> when I changed the template to default template the problem solved.

This indicates that the problem might be with your template.

1. If possible, upload your entire site again, to make sure all files where transferred correctly. I suggest using [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) when moving your site to another server.
2. Make sure Joomla and your extensions are updated, as well as the template you're using.
3. As Anibal pointed out, your servers might have different settings. Check and compare PHP and MySQL versions on your servers.
4. Disable/unpublish your plugins and modules one by one, in case any of them has a conflict with your template.